# How to use the results of a CTE query inside another query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression

I want to take the result of a CTE query and use it inside another query.

This simplified example uses a CTE query to return a list of ids.

```
with test_cte (id,name) as (
    select id, name
    from test
)
select id
from test_cte
where name = 'john'
```

I want to use this list of ids to delete some records like this but I'm getting a syntax error:

```
delete from test
where id in (
    with test_cte (id,name) as (
        select id, name
        from test
    )
    select id
    from test_cte
    where name = 'john'
)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A CTE is defined at the *start* of your statement, not the middle.

Comment: So I can't use it like a subquery, correct?

Comment: It's not a subquery, @Madison, it's a CTE (common table expression): [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#f-using-a-recursive-cte-in-an-update-statement). A CTE is always defined at the *start* of the statement, as shown in the linked documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid of that.

Comment: You can reference the CTE directly for your delete

Comment: Might be a dumb question, but why don't you adapt your CTE  to just contain the values you need from the beginning instead of including them first and removing them later.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can't use it in a DML statement though, @Madison320 , you're just using it wrong...

Comment: @Stu: I think you're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just mean this:

```
;with test_cte(id,name) as
(
  select id,name from dbo.test
)
delete test_cte where name='john';
```

Do you want to delete rows *and* show the rows you deleted?

```
;with test_cte(id,name) as
(
  select id,name from dbo.test
)
delete test_cte 
output deleted.id, deleted.name
where name='john';
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d52009f3ff08eb8c62ccda803da2d247)

To take your explicit example:

```
delete from test
where id in (
    with test_cte (id,name) as (
        select id, name
        from test
    )
    select id
    from test_cte
    where name = 'john'
)
```

You're getting a syntax error because, well, there's an error in your syntax. CTE must be defined up front, not in any random or arbitrary point in your query.

```
;with test_cte (id,name) as (
    select id, name
    from test
)
delete from test
where id in (
    select id
    from test_cte
    where name = 'john'
)
```

But this still seems awfully over-complicated compared to the simpler examples I've shown.

Comment: I must admit, it really still confuses me that you're on the side that fence that treats the semi-colon as a "beginninator".

Comment: No my actual example is much more complicated. I was trying to use CTE to make it more readable.

Comment: @Larnu because will still copy and paste that into a procedure that has `DECLARE @name varchar(32) = 'john'` and then yell at me that I broke their code. Consider it permanent.

Comment: Then perhaps you should be giving a more representative example, @Madison320 .

Comment: But that's not your fault that *their* code was broken in the first place, @AaronBertrand . ;) One day, that deprecated syntax will break their *entire* instance. 

Comment: I try to keep business logic out of my questions.

Comment: The last example was what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see how the first examples would work. Wouldn't that only delete from the in memory CTE table not the test table?

Comment: I might be wrong, but wouldn't the following be more readable `with cte (...)  as (...)  delete test from test inner join cte on test.id = cte.id where cte.id = 'john'` instead of `where id in (select ...)`

Comment: @derpirscher The CTE is updatable, meaning if you update the CTE, you update its source (test). There is no point to then join again to the source table (or use a WHERE clause to reference back to it). That's one of the over-complicated parts I was talking about.

Comment: @Madison320 [did you try it?](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b6e63d544bcc12d8c632db91c2c6efda) The CTE isn't "in memory" as such. It's just a table expression.

Comment: Ahh, I see. It's working when I tested it as well. Sorry, I skipped your other answers as soon as I saw that first one.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Yes, it is in that simple example because it is only contstructed from one table (and it might indeed work for OP in the current usecase). But as soon, as the CTE is more complex and joins multiple tables, this won't work any more.

Comment: One thing I see mentioned on other comments, the semicolon at the start is not mandatory for the WITH to work, right?
I always see examples of WITH's with the semicolon before and wonder.

Comment: @derpirscher If the CTE involved joins or otherwise became non-updateable, that's the question the OP should have asked.

Comment: @ThomasDoconski See up the comment thread. The reason is that people take `WITH ...` code samples and paste it into their existing code without semi-colons on prior statements. Then we get blamed for giving them bad code. You can have as many semi-colons before and after statements as you want, so there is no _harm_ in insulating yourself from that up front, except having to explain yourself. I'm starting to wonder which is worse.

Comment: @derpirscher: yeah, in my real example I'm not even deleting from the CTE. Normally I can write a sql statement, put parens around it and treat it like a table but not so with CTE.

Comment: @Madison320 If you want your complex query in the middle, then just use a subquery, it's the same as a CTE it just doesn't start with `WITH` and can go in more places.

Comment: @Aaron: If I knew that much about CTEs I wouldn't be her asking! :)

Comment: In that case @AaronBertrand has a very valid point: you asked the wrong question, ie you oversimplified and thus the best answer to your question won't work in your real world usecase ...

Comment: Fair point @AaronBertrand

Comment: @Aaron Thanks, yeah I was about use a normal subquery but now that you helped me figure it out I think it's more readable with the CTE.

Comment: @Larnu I'm on the side of putting `;` on *both* ends, but I'm not always so strict. i always terminate